# WP Query - if/else using custom field

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have a WP query that is looping all my projects with the same code. It's working great, but now I need to change the code based on a custom taxonomy. I basically want to make an if/else loop where if the custom taxonomy contains a certain value, to have x code, and if the custom taxonomy does not contain that certain value, to have y code. Is there a way to add this if/else statement to the "if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :" section? Or do I need to lay this out differently?

Thank you!

```html
<?php 
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page' => 24,
    'paged' => $paged,
); 

$the_query = new WP_Query($args); 

if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

?>
```

EDIT: FluffyKitten (great name) asked for more info so here it is.
My custom taxonomy is called "project_services" and I want all projects with the service "commercial-damages" to loop through with one code, and all other projects to loop through with another code. I tried my crack at it below, but know that my part in the if loop is extremely wrong. I'm really not sure how to add that if condition in there since it's a WP query.

```
<?php 
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page' => 24,
    'paged' => $paged,
); 

$the_query = new WP_Query($args); 

if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

if (get_field('project_services') == 'commercial-damages'): 
    ?>  


<div class="projects-column">
<div class="project-image">
<?php $image = get_field('image');
if( !empty($image) ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="project-image-tester" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="project-info">
<span class="proj-name" style="font-weight: bold;"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></span>
</div>


<div class="project-onhover">
<span class="proj-title"><p><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></p></span>
<span class="proj-details">
<p><span style="font-weight: bold;">LOCATION: </span><?php the_field('location'); ?></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: bold;">CLAIM VALUE: </span><?php the_field('project_value'); ?></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: bold;">SERVICES: </span> <?php echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'project_services', '', ', ', '' ) ); ?> </p></span>
</div><!--projects-on-hover-tester -->
</div><!--project-image-->
</div><!--projects-column -->
    
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="projects-column">
<div class="project-image">
<?php $image = get_field('image');
if( !empty($image) ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="project-image-tester" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="project-info">
<span class="proj-name" style="font-weight: bold;"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></span>
</div>


<div class="project-onhover">
<span class="proj-title"><p><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></p></span>
<span class="proj-details">
<p><span style="font-weight: bold;">LOCATION: </span><?php the_field('location'); ?></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: bold;">PROJECT VALUE: </span><?php the_field('project_value'); ?></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: bold;">SERVICES: </span> <?php echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'project_services', '', ', ', '' ) ); ?> </p></span>
</div><!--projects-on-hover-tester -->
</div><!--project-image-->
</div><!--projects-column --> 

<?PHP endif; ?>

<?php 
endwhile;
endif;
?>


  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do in that if/else! Please show us an example of what you are trying to do, so we can understand and be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I just tried giving you some more info. Did that help?

Comment: Thanks for adding more info, but I'm still not entirely sure what you want to do *in* the if/else. For example, do you just want to display/process the `commercial-damages` differently, or did you want to separate them out so that all the `commercial-damages` are displayed together and separately from everything else?

Comment: Gotcha. I want all the projects to still be laid out in the same order (as outlined in the args), I just want to pass a different title in the HTML for commercial damages projects. There's a title "Value", and for commercial damages projects I want this to say "Claim Value" instead of value. It's just the HTML in the loop code. I'm not trying to change the order or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to change the way you are processing the post details in your loop, so you don't need to make any changes to the loop itself. What you want to do is check the custom field *inside* the loop and then decide what to do with it.

Also FYI, you are using `the_field` - this will display the result to the screen immediately. Instead, to use the value without automatically displaying it, use [`get_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

Take a look at this - there are additional comments to help explain what it happening:

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query($args); 

// Standard while loop to get each of the returned posts one by one - 
// we don't care what the post type is here, we just load it into the global "post" so we can use it... 
if( $the_query->have_posts(); while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query- 
>the_post(); 

    // Now the details of that post are loaded into the global "post",
    // so we can check the values in that post

    // Check if the current post in out loop has commercial-damages
    if (get_field('project_services') === 'commercial-damages'): 
    ?>    
        // do whatever you want with the commercial-damages posts...    
    <?php else: ?>
        // do whatever you want with the other posts
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php 
endwhile;
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been playing around with this for a bit now, and the if clause (if (get_field('project_services') === 'commercial-damages'): 
    ?>    ) does not seem to be working. I've tried a few different ways and can't get that one to work.

Comment: Try changing the `===` - that's a strict comparison. It's unlikely that the problem but best to rule it out! Then check the value in `project_services` to make sure it is what you expect - just before the line `if (get_field(....` add `var_dump(get_field('project_services'));` This will show the value that is being retrieved for that field. If that doesn't help you with the problem, let me know what the value is and what is it set up as in ACF and we can take it from there :)

Comment: @KathleenHaynes I forgot to tag you in my comment so I'm not sure if you got a notification :)

Comment: I changed === to == and still nothing. Then I did the var_dump code and you're right, it's coming up as "null". The taxonomy name/slug is "project_services" and the slug for the term I need is "commercial-damages". I tried "has_terms('commercial-damages', 'project_services')" but that didn't work either. I just updated the my question above with all my code so you can see the HTML parts.

Comment: @KathleenHaynes Is the ACF field in a repeater or group or anything Can you use `var_dump(get_fields());` - this will show *all* the ACF fields for the post - and show us what it outputs, this should give us a better idea of the structure of your fields.

Comment: @KathleenHaynes Were you able to get values from the var_dump? Did that help you work out the field to use, or do you need more help with this?

Comment: Yes I was able to show the values using var_dump but that just confused me more. For some reason project_services did not show up. This is how i'm calling the field: <?php echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'project_services', '', ', ', '' ) ); ?>

Comment: I started trying a different approach, where I just used an if statement inside the HTML loop section. I created a "Claims Value" custom field, and wanted to make an if statement with, if the project value is not empty, display that, and is the claims value is not empty, show that. <?php if( get_field('project_value') ): ?><p><span style="font-weight: bold;">PROJECT VALUE: </span><?php the_field('project_value'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
<?php if( get_field('claims_value') ): ?><p><span style="font-weight: bold;">CLAIMS VALUE: </span><?php the_field('claims_value'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>

Comment: but for some reason this doesn't seem to be working either....of course!

Comment: I just got that to work! Mistakenly wasn't using the else: function. Thank you for your help, i'm sorry I was such a pain!! <?php if( get_field('project_value') ): ?><p><span style="font-weight: bold;">PROJECT VALUE: </span><?php the_field('project_value'); ?></p>
 <?php else: ?>
<p><span style="font-weight: bold;">CLAIMS VALUE: </span><?php the_field('claims_value'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to FluffyKitten who helped me work through this. I wasn't able to get an if loop to work exactly how outlined in the question, but I tried a few other approaches and just got one to work. I created an if / else statement in the HTML that I am looping. There I put if this field is empty, use another which I created and labeled differently to solve my problem. Below is the code:

```
    <?php if( get_field('project_value') ): ?><p><span style="font-weight: bold;">PROJECT VALUE: </span><?php the_field('project_value'); ?></p> 
<?php else: ?> 
<p><span style="font-weight: bold;">CLAIMS VALUE: </span><?php the_field('claims_value'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
```